# How to run Memgraph using the same Memgraph platform Docker image but with volume?

Tags: docker, graph-databases, memgraphdb

Is there any info on how to run Memgraph using the same Memgraph platform Docker image, but with a volume so that the data persists between restarts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try running:

```
docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 3000:3000 \
-v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph \
-v mg_log:/var/log/memgraph \
-v mg_etc:/etc/memgraph \
memgraph/memgraph-platform
```